# Problem in the utf-8 encoding of an API response

Tags: json, angular

I am making a request to an API but it does not return the json with format utf-8, for example, the word "Panamá" shows it to me like this: ""Panam\u00e1"", add this to the header of the request http: 'Content -Type ':' application / json; charset = UTF-8 ', verify that if it is being sent in the request but I still receive the same answer. If I make the request from Postman everything is returned well, what could it be? I would be grateful to the one who can help me.

So I have the header of my request now:

```js
  headboard = {
    'Accept': 'application/json;charset=utf-8',
    'Authorization': "",
    'Accept-Charset': 'UTF-8'
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct HTTP header for *requesting* JSON as UTF-8 is

```
Accept: application/json;charset=utf-8
```

whilst `Content-Type` is just the descriptive HTTP header containing information for the *consumer* - which is superfluous if you don't *send* any data.

Edit: It is also possible to pass the encoding explicitely via the header

```
Accept-Charset: UTF-8
```

Comment: Hi Smutje , I forgot to mention that that was the first thing I tried and it did not work either. I'm placing it like this: 'Accept': 'application / json; charset = utf-8', but when I check in the "network" tab of my browser, in the header of the request, it appears like this: Accept: application / json, I do not know why.

Comment: it still does not work, now I have it like this: headboard = {
     'Accept': 'application / json',
     'Authorization': "",
     'Accept-Charset': 'UTF-8'
   }

Comment: Can you compare your headers with the headers sent by Postman?

Comment: Also, is there actually a space between "application" and "json"? If yes, please remove it and replace it with (literally) `application/json;charset=utf-8`.

Comment: there are no spaces, edit my question so you can see how I currently have it.

Comment: OK, so other than literally comparing every header Postman sends with your headers I have no idea.